# LINQ TO SQL: HAVING COUNT(table_id) < 2

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm building a website for an school and i need a list of users that don't have 2 parents asigned. This would be the SQL query:

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_rol = 4
AND user_id IN 
(SELECT parent_user_id FROM user_parents
GROUP BY parent_user_id
HAVING COUNT(parent_user_id) < 2);
```

I'm trying to use LINQ for the same query but I don't know how to use HAVING with LINQ. This has been my closer try for the moment.

SUB-QUERY FOR IN

```
List<long> usersWithTwoParentsIds = (from currentStudents in contexto.user_parents
select currentStudents.parent_user_id).ToList<long>();
--HELP! having count(currentStudents.parent_user_id) < 2
```

QUERY

```
List<vw_user> userList = (from currentStudents in contexto.vw_user
where !usersWithTwoParentsIds.Contains(currentStudents.user_id)
&& currentStudents.group_id == groupID select currentStudents).ToList<vw_user>()
```

Can anybody give a clue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var usersWithTwoParentsIds = (
    from userParent in contexto.user_parents
    group userParent by userParent.parent_user_id into userParentGroups
    where userParentGroups.Count() < 2
    select userParentGroups.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key relations are proper in your data context:

```
var dat = Context.Users.Where( u => u.Parents.Count() < 2 );
```